# Inconsistent Error sending email in CRM: unable to find one-to-many relationship, entity: systemuser, referencing entity: activityparty

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

We are experiencing a strange error that seems to be inconsistent. Several users have reported not being able to save or send an email in our CRM. Instead we get this error:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Pzp.png)

This is also happening for at least four users including System Administrators. However, it does not happen consistently. Saving or sending an email may work or may get this error. If we refresh the page and try the same steps we may get the opposite result. It is possible that it is getting more common.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this error under these circumstances?

No changes that I'm aware of. It doesn't seem to be an issue with permissions, business units, or security roles. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.